# Invoke lightning web component from vf page on apex:command button click

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

**I have a apex:commandButton on which I have to open my lightning web component. But I'm not able to achieve it. `Requirement : On vf page only button should be visible. After button in clicked it should open lwc component on new tab or window.` I created a function which gets called on button click and then calling `openLwc` function to invoke lwc but it dosen't work.**

*.vf page*

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:includeLightning />    
        <div id="LightningComponentid" />    
        <script>
        function buttonClick(){
            console.log('Method Called');
            window.open();
            openLwc();
        }
        
        function openLwc(){
        $Lightning.use("c:lwcvf", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent("c:lwccmponvf",
                                           { 
                                           },
                                           "LightningComponentid",
                                           function(cmp) {
                                               console.log('LWC Componenet added in VF page');
                                           });
            });
}
        </script>
        
        
        <apex:commandButton title="Demo Button" value="Demo Button" onclick="buttonClick();"   />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

*lwcvf.app*

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="GLOBAL">
    <aura:dependency resource="lwccmponvf" />
</aura:application>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console? What actually happens ("it doesn't work" isn't very precise)? Please [edit] the question to add more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using a little hack.

```
<script>
    function openLwc(){
        window.open('/lightning/n/lwccmponvf')
    }
</script>
```

I am directly calling this function from my apex:commandButton and it's working fine.